# what is difference between normal string passing to view resolver and passing with redirect:/string in spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller

I have two methods in a controller. view resolver is configured in the servlet.xml

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test2")
    public String test2(Model model) 
    {
        System.out.println("redirected 1");
        return "test3";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/test3")
    public String test3(Model model) 
    {
        System.out.println("redirected 2");
        return "redirect:/test2";
    }
```

can anyone tell me what is difference between those 2 as current both methods are opening mentioned jsp page for me..

Answer (score 0):

In first option you just open view name.
Second option is using the prefix redirect:. The redirect view name is injected into the controller like any other logical view name. The controller is not even aware that redirection is happening.

Comment: i don't think that's a sufficient answer for me to understand it. can you give some example if possible?